# Key X not found or not valid with Xubuntu, Enigmail and Thunderbird

Tags: xubuntu, encryption, thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

I try to run GnuPG with Enigmail and Thunderbird. At first it seems that everything runs perfectly: I am able to encrypt / decrypt files. Only Thunderbird with Enigmail doesn't work. I always get the error:

```
Key X not found or not valid. The (sub-)key might have expired.
```

My key is - of course - valid and not expired. It works if I start Thunderbird as root, but all rights of the files seems OK. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a pinentry package installed? Try:

```
sudo apt-get install pinentry-gtk2
```

See: http://baitisj.blogspot.com/2014/07/enigmail-key-not-found-or-not-valid.html